# Cancelling OngoingEvent Android Notifications

Tags: android

I've been fighting this for over a week now, so any help would be appreciated.

I have an Activity starting a Service for media playback. Once playback has begun, the Service starts an Ongoing, Non-Cancellable Notification as such:

```
realIntent = new Intent(this, EpisodeViewer.class);
realIntent.putExtra("show_name", showName);
realIntent.putExtra("episode_name", episodeName);

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, realIntent, 0);

note =
    new Notification(
        R.drawable.ic_notification_bcn,
        episodeName,
        System.currentTimeMillis());
note.flags =
    note.flags |
    Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE |
    Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR |
    Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "", episodeName, pendingIntent);

note.contentView =
    new RemoteViews(
        getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
        R.layout.episode_player_note);
note.contentView.setImageViewResource(
    R.id.player_note_icon,
    R.drawable.ic_notification_bcn);
 note.contentView.setTextViewText(
    R.id.player_note_text,
    episodeName);
note.contentView.setProgressBar(
    R.id.player_note_progress, 100, 0, false);

noteManager.notify(MEDIA_PLAYER_NOTIFY_ID, note);
```

And this works just fine. When the user switches to play something else (through the Activity's UI) the Service updates the Notification (using the same as above) to change the name and re-set the progress bar. And this works just fine. And as the media progresses, the progress bar in the Notification updates, and this works as well.

But when the media ends or the User wants to stop, the Service tries to cancel the Notification with

```
noteManager.cancel(MEDIA_PLAYER_NOTIFY_ID);
```

But this is ignored. There are no errors in the DDMS log, but from my trace I know for sure the cancel is being called. I've tried cancelling the PendingIntent before cancelling the Notification, but this makes no difference. I've also tried replacing the Notification with an 'Empty' one - clearing the progress and the name - and then cancelling. The new 'Cleared' Notification shows, but then still does not cancel.

So what am I missing here? Is there something else that needs to be done to cancel a FOREGROUND or NO_CLEAR or ONGOING Notification that I'm missing? I've tried this with the Emulator under 2.1 and 2.2, and on my hardware running 2.3, all of which exhibit the exact same behaviour.

Comment: I'd get rid of `FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE`, or try to get rid of the `Notification` by using `stopForeground()`.

Comment: Removing the FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE flag allows me to cancel the Notification. Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same problem.

If the notification flag has "Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE" in it, the only way to get rid of it is to call "stopForeground()", but there is a catch. The "stopForeground()" won't remove the notification (with FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE) if "startForeground()" has not been called!

In simple words, if you use FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE, you have to call "startForeground()" and "stopForeground()"!

If "startForeground()" is used, I don't see a reason for putting FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE in the other notifications. But if it is needed, here is a sample (used in public class CLASS extends Service) :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    PendingIntent notifIntent;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();  // fill up yourself
    notifIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity();  // fill up yourself

    Notification note = new Notification();  // fill up yourself
    note.setLatestEventInfo(context, getString(R.string.app_name), Message, notifIntent);  

    startForeground(yourOwnNumber, note);  // fill up yourself

    displayYourNotification();

    // Fill up the rest yourself.
}


public void onDestroy() {
    stopForeground();  // fill up yourself
}


public void displayYourNotification() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();  // fill up yourself
    notifIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification note = new Notification();  // fill up yourself
    note.flags = Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;
    note.setLatestEventInfo(context, TITLE, Message, notifIntent);  
    notifManager.notify(ID, note);
}
```